# Why is my 4 lines all printing ontop of each other when printing

Tags: c#, winforms

```
e.Graphics.DrawString("Grand Total: £ " +grdtotal , new Font("Century Gothic", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Crimson, new Point(60, pos + 50));
e.Graphics.DrawString("***The Android Dungeon*** \n", new Font("Century Gothic", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Crimson, new Point(40, pos + 85));
e.Graphics.DrawString("Thank you - " + CusName.Text + "\n" , new Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Blue, new Point(40, pos));
            
e.Graphics.DrawString("\n" + Addresstb.Text + "\n", new Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Blue, new Point(80, pos )); 
            
e.Graphics.DrawString("\n" + Postcodetb.Text + "\n", new Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Blue, new Point(100, pos )); 
            
e.Graphics.DrawString("\n" + towntb.Text + "\n", new Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Blue, new Point(120, pos ));
```

when I print on the receipt it all prints on top of each other when its meant to be different lines I've used the \n

to print on different lines but they are all printing ontop of each other it shouldnt be like that i put the \n in and it still didnt print on a new line ?

Comment: Just a hunch ... but you provide a Point .... maybe that is where it is printed at? Did you read the API-Description?  you most probably can get rid of the \n  and move the point some pixels down .... `e.Graphics.DrawString( "some text", new Font("Century Gothic", 12, FontStyle.Bold), Brushes.Crimson, new Point(60, pos + 50));`  <<<- the last param - tha last 4 statements share the same `pos` as y-Value - hence Over Each Other ...

Comment: The `\n`s are irrelevant - they don't produce any output. What's relevant is the *coordinates* you're passing in your method call - after all, how is `DrawString` meant to know how much space you intended there to be between those lines - *you* are controlling all of the drawing.

Comment: Unrelated: How about _reusing_ a `Font` object?

Comment: I suspect you are expecting, you _are_ moving the Point **down**. You aren't. X is left-to-right getting bigger starting 0 and Y is from **top to bottom** getting bigger starting at 0. So, 0,0 is your upperleft corner. To move **down** you need to **increase Y**.

Comment: In that context: I'd recommend to use one of the [MeasureString](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) overloads to see how much you actually need to translate the point in order to have no overlap.

Answer (score 1):

Let's improve on your example - note comments

```
// You are using 2 different Font sizes, so let's create reusable instances:
var fontBigBold = new Font("Century Gothic", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
var fontNormal  = new Font("Century Gothic", 8, FontStyle.Bold);

// Let's shorten the Brushes, too for Readablity
var crimson = Brushes.Crimson;
var blue = Brushes.Blue;

// let's have the computer compute, not our brain.
var linePtr = pos + 50;

e.Graphics.DrawString($"Grand Total: £ {grdtotal}" , 
               fontBigBold , crimson, 
               new Point(60, linePtr)); // <-- you already were on the right track!?
linePtr += 35;
// \n does nothing for you! Let's ditch those.
e.Graphics.DrawString("***The Android Dungeon***", fontBigBold , crimson, new Point(40, linePtr));
linePtr += 35;
e.Graphics.DrawString($"Thank you - {CusName.Text}" , fontNormal, blue, new Point(40, linePtr));
linePtr += 35;            
e.Graphics.DrawString($"{Addresstb.Text}", fontNormal, blue, new Point(40, linePtr)); 
linePtr += 35;
e.Graphics.DrawString($"{Postcodetb.Text}", fontNormal, blue, new Point(40, linePtr)); 
linePtr += 35;
e.Graphics.DrawString($"{towntb.Text}", fontNormal, blue, new Point(40, linePtr));
```

For simplicity, I just assumed a line height of 35 here. I'd actually get the line height by using [`MeasureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.measurestring?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) with a single "M" if it's only the height, that's interesting.

Like so

```
int lineHeight = (int)e.Graphics.MeasureString("M", fontBigBold).Height + somePadding;
```

Further improvements:

- I'd try to refactor, so the repeating parts are in functions and this code can focus on the actual purpose.
- I'd again use `MeasureString` to **make sure the strings won't actually get too big (long)**. For the case they *do* you can think of different solutions like ellipis or break the line ... up to you.